# Keycodes for the Numeric Keypad

Tags: numbers, ascii, keypad

I was looking at the Stack Overflow questions to see if there was a keycode for the number keypad (the keys on the right of the keyboard). A list of useful answers was given but also confusing. Apparently Numpad-0 is 96, Numpad-1 is 97, Numpad-2 is 98, and so on.

This would be alright except that isn't 97 already allocated to capital A and 98 to capital B?

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am searching for the same and I found it; here is the code:

```
KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD0 to KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD9
```

Comment: Very much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

The Javascript **Keycodes** differ from the ASCII codes (called **Character Codes** in javascript) sadly, because ASCII doesn't differentiate between a 1 from the top of the keyboard and a 1 from the number pad - they are the same character. Likewise the javascript key codes don't differentate between a capital and lowercase letter, because they are the same key...

The ASCII codes are shown here: http://www.asciitable.com/index/asciifull.gif

and the Javascript key codes here: https://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes

This page (https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_key_keycode.asp) describes the difference;

The difference between the two code types:

> Character codes - A number which represents an ASCII character
>
> Key codes - A number which represents an actual key on the keyboard
>
> These types do not always mean the same thing; for example, a lower case "w"
> and an upper case "W" have the same keyboard code, because the key
> that is pressed on the keyboard is the same (just "W" = the number
> "87"), but a different character code because the resulting character
> is different (either "w" or "W", which is "119" or "87") - See "More
> Examples" below to better understand it.

Comment: Ouch! Thanks. Seems like the more systems we have, the worse it gets...